# How to replace variable inside ternaryoperation using groovy script engine

Tags: groovy, groovyscriptengine

I am using Groovy SimpleTemplateEngine to set values dynamically at run time. I am using ternary operator as well inside the string. Values are not getting updated for the variables inside the ternary operator. Can someone please help how to achieve this?

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
        SimpleTemplateEngine engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine();
        Template template = engine.createTemplate(f);
        def refMap = [:]
        refMap["condition1"] = "true";
        refMap["acctNbr"] = "1234567890";
        refMap["value"] = "abc";
        println template.make(refMap).toString();

test.txt

<acctNbr13>${acctNbr}</acctNbr13>
${(
Boolean.parseBoolean(condition1)
?
'''
<test>${value}</test>
'''
:
''
)}
```

Comment: Is this not just the fact that triple-single-quote is a string literal, not a triple-double-quote GString?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the String already represents the replaced value and does not get parsed itself.

Would it work for you to replace

```
 '''
 <test>${value}</test>
 '''
```

with

```
 '<test>' + value + '</test>'
```